# ImageMagick Detect Text Block

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Has anyone succeeded in detecting a text block in image magick? (or any other image library) Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [OCROpus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) and look for the page segmentation features.